# Which bucket triggered lambda on object creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have multiple s3 buckets set up to trigger a lambda function on object creation.
I would like to know which one triggered the lambda, how to find out?

Answer (score 1):

The **Event** sent to the AWS Lambda function includes the Bucket Name and Object Key.

See: [Event Message Structure - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/notification-content-structure.html)

You can access it with code like this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    // Read options from the event.
    console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
    var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
    var srcKey    =
    decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

(This code sample is from: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html))